# How to create directives elements programmatically?

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

*Angular 1.4.8*

How can I create directive elements programmatically inside a controller? I tried [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) but it doesn't work for me.

**Controller and directive**

```
angular.module('plunker', [])
.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $compile) {
  var container = angular.element(document.getElementById('container'));
  $scope.user = {item: 'Axe'};

  var item = angular.element(document.createElement('anItem'));
  item = $compile(item)($scope);

  container.append(item);
})
.directive('anItem', function(){
  return {
    templateUrl: 'template.html'
  };
});
```

**template.html**

```
<p>Item: {{user.item}}</p>
```

**index.html**

```
...
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div id="container"></div>
</body>
...
```

Here is my plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/XY6C6J70PjQTrjiwjHSz?p=preview

Comment: can't you use ng-if in your html? and set a flag in your controller on wich render or not it?

Comment: It's just a casing problem: `document.createElement('an-item')` instead of `anItem`

Comment: @lex82 you are right, thank you! Post your answer and I'll rate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the name of the directive is "anItem", the DOM elements are named "an-item". This is just the Angular naming convention. This works:

```
document.createElement('an-item')
```

Here is the updated [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/NEeR6DtqV7LQA1RH6W5U?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

```
var elm = angular.element('<an-item"></an-item>');
container.append(elm);

scope.$applyAsync(function () {
    $compile(elm)(scope);
});
```